# Flutter- WebView Content Security Policy

Tags: html, flutter, webview, android-webview, vimeo

I am using  webview_flutter: ^1.0.0 package in my flutter app and I get this bellow warning:

E/libEGL  (16177): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
I/chromium(16177): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to load the image 'android-webview-video-poster:default_video_poster/-1319672160645029230' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: https://i.vimeocdn.com https://secure-b.vimeocdn.com https://f.vimeocdn.com https://vimeo.com https://secure.gravatar.com https://i0.wp.com https://i1.wp.com https://i2.wp.com https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com https://player.vimeo.com https://*.ci.vimeows.com https://f.vimeocdn.com".
I/chromium(16177): ", source: https://player.vimeo.com/video/111111111 (0)

Here is my code:

```
         class WebViewVideoPlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  static const routName = '/vimeoPlayerWidget-page';


  @override
  _WebViewVideoPlayerWidgetState createState() => _WebViewVideoPlayerWidgetState();
}

class _WebViewVideoPlayerWidgetState extends State<WebViewVideoPlayerWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode();
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  String iframeUrl = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/462891972";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final length = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([]);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: length.height,
        width: length.width,
        child: WebView(
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          initialUrl: iframeUrl,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    AutoOrientation.landscapeAutoMode();
    AutoOrientation.portraitUpMode();
    super.dispose();
  }

}
```

How can I fix the error?